# Unstacked/Regular area chart in NVD3?

Tags: javascript, charts, nvd3.js

I see that the [current Area Charts](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html) that NVD3 has are Stacked Area Charts. I would like to use the regular area charts / unstacked area charts in my project, the plotting of each needs to start from `(0,0)` with a different color. The closest that I could get was using the [Simple Line Chart](http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html) with the area filled, but I am loosing the feature where I could click on a particular area and get that plotted solely.

Is there a way I can get an unstacked area chart with the interactive features like the [stacked area chart](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html)?

Comment: From the 3 option `Stacked`, `Stream` and `Expanded` provided by NVD3 stacked charts, which one are you planning on using?

Comment: @shabeer90 Actually, I dont want any of them. I want to plot an area chart like this one: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart If you can notice, plotting for both areas here starts from `(0,0)` and it is not stacked.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is not a direct approach. You might have to use plain `d3`.

Have a look at this [`question & its answers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962375/how-to-disable-some-streams-by-default-in-a-nvd3-simple-line-chart) might give you a starting point.

If you find a solution, please do share.

Cheers